# How to remove strings ending with certain pattern from list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following code snippet:

```
result = {
             "cast": [],
         } | {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
cast_value = (', '.join(result.get("cast", None)))
```

Now sometimes I have a very long cast list, that often ends with e.g. "Ted Rai..." this is always the last entry in the list. Seems that somebody has cut off the 255 characters. How can I remove the last entry from my list if it ends with  `"..."`?

I use `', '` as separator between my strings.

If needed:

```
def get_plist_names(name_dict):
    return [o["string"] for o in (name_dict if isinstance(name_dict, list) else [name_dict])]
```

Comment: What have you tried? did you tried to convert it to list?

Comment: Use the `.endswith()` function.

Comment: Did you mean `or` rather than `|`?

Comment: @DarrylG The `|` operator merges dictionaries. Try: `{"a": 1} | {"b": 2}`

Comment: Okay, see the code I have written is working fine but now I simply want to remove a string from my list if it ends with "..." That's all.

Comment: @Barmar--I see it must be for Python 3.9+.  I'm using 3.8 and it gives `unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator with `if` condition when calling `join()`.

```
cast_value = (', '.join(r for r in result.get("cast", None) if not r.endswith("...")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! exactly what I have searched for.